# Autodesk Forge Viewer : Open PDF from HTTP

Tags: pdf, autodesk-forge, autodesk, viewer, forge

I am trying to view PDF using GuiViewer3D viewer. My PDF file is located on a server and I am getting following errors (see image below). I can open local PDF file without any problem. Is there any settings/configuration to load PDF file from a HTTP URL in this viewer.

Thank you for your support and help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoJTK.png)

Here is my code:

```
/**
* Initialize viewer
*
* @memberof NestedViewerPanel
*/
initializeViewer( pdf ) {
    var options = {
            //env: "Local",
            useADP: false,
            method: "POST",
            url: pdf
}

/**
* Creater and initialize 3D viewer for PDF document
*
* @memberof NestedViewerPanel
*/
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(this._container);
    viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
    viewer.start(options);
    const localFilePath = './pdf/';

    if (!pdf) return;
    viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then( () => {
        //viewer.loadModel(localFilePath + pdf , viewer);
        viewer.loadModel( pdf , viewer);
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui");
    });
 });
}
```

Comment: Your error is CORS related. Your server is blocking calls from your app because it has not been configured to accept them. You could temporarily allow acces for localhost:3000 but this is a bit of a last resort. You're better of testing with local server first and then aligning stuff when you go to production. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your help. We were able to change setting on server side and it works fine.